# Coin sum with negative coin values

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I managed to write this code to find minimum coin sum to get to an exact amount of value. But I wrote this considering positive coin values.

Can someone give me an idea how to upgrade this code to compute minimum coin sum with negative coin values?
Thank you in advance!

```
int main()
{
 int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
 int m = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
 int n = 4;
 printf(" %d ", count(arr, m, n));
 return 0;
}


int count( int S[], int m, int n )
{
 int i, j, x, y;

 int table[n+1][m];

 for (i=0; i<m; i++)
    table[0][i] = 1;
  // Fill rest of the table enteries in bottom up manner
  for (i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        // Count of solutions including S[j]
        x = (i-S[j] >= 0)? table[i - S[j]][j]: 0;
        // Count of solutions excluding S[j]
        y = (j >= 1)? table[i][j-1]: 0;
        // total count
        table[i][j] = x + y;
    }
}
return table[n][m-1];
}
```

Comment: First, do you realise that your current solution is never allowed to choose the same coin more than once?  I mention this because problems stated in terms of making change with coins often use a set of coin *types*, which can be used as many times as you want, rather than a fixed set of *coins*.

Comment: Second, assuming that you want to continue treating the problem as a set of coins rather than coin types, I would suggest starting by dealing with all the negative coins first, and building "downwards": conceptually, you want to calculate `table[i][j]` for all `min <= i < 0`, where `min` is the sum of all negative coins.  (Of course you can't index an array with a negative subscript, so you'll need some other scheme, e.g. an offset.)  Then you can work back up as usual.

Comment: What is a "negative coin value"? Why is the word "coin" used here at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you want to use each coin an arbitrary number of times (as is usually how the problem is stated), or whether you want to use each coin just 0 or 1 times (which is what your code implies).

If you are allowed to use each coin an arbitrary number of times, then perhaps the conceptually simplest solution is to build a graph on nodes numbered 0 to N where N is the sum of all positive coin values, and then connect nodes i and j with a directed edge if (j-i) is one of your coin values, and then run Dijkstra's algorithm where all edges have weight 1 to find shortest paths from 0 to all other nodes in the graph, which will include your target value. You can backtrack to find the specific optimal solution for your target value.

If you are only allowed to use each coin at most once, then you can assume without loss of generality that the optimal solution for a given target value will first use all positive coins and then use all negative coins. So you can build up the optimal solutions for values 0 to N using all positive coins (where again N is the sum of all positive coin values) using breadth first search where you keep track of how many coins it takes to make each target value and the last coin used in the optimal solution, and then order the positive coins and then take one coin at a time, and consider adding each coin to each value you can currently obtain to see if you can obtain a new value using a fewer number of coins. Then after you have computed all the optimal solutions using just positive coins, you order the negative value coins and similarly process the optimal solution array in the reverse direction.